# How to extract the Table Definitions of a MYSQL Table into CSV?

Tags: mysql, csv

The output of `mysqldump -not csv` does not contain the columns, just values:

```
select * from AUDIT_RESULT 
INTO OUTFILE '/va/tmp/audit_nresult.csv'

FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

It does not contain the column names just the values. How to get the column names also?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040816/dump-all-tables-in-csv-format-using-mysqldump does this solve your Issue?

Comment: See also https://hevodata.com/learn/mysql-export-to-csv/

Answer (score 1):

Export Table into CSV Format Using MySQL Workbench

1. Run the statement/query and get its result set.
2. Then, in the result panel, click "export recordset to an external file" option. The recordset is used for the result set.
3. Finally, a new dialog box will be displayed. Here, we need to provide a filename and its format.